# Exception: Cannot import python-ntlm module

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am using suds 0.4 and running into below error,I read on the web the above issue is fixed since 0.3.8..so am wondering what is wrong here?

```
  File "script.py", line 532, in <module>
    prism = Prism('http://prism:8000/SearchService.svc?wsdl')
  File "script.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.CR_soapclient = Client(self.CR_url, transport=WindowsHttpAuthenticated(username=user, password=passwd))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/wsdl.py", line 136, in __init__
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/reader.py", line 79, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/reader.py", line 95, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/transport/https.py", line 60, in open
    return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/transport/http.py", line 62, in open
    return self.u2open(u2request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/transport/http.py", line 113, in u2open
    url = self.u2opener()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/transport/http.py", line 127, in u2opener
    return u2.build_opener(*self.u2handlers())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg/suds/transport/https.py", line 95, in u2handlers
    raise Exception("Cannot import python-ntlm module")
Exception: Cannot import python-ntlm module
```

Suds version

```
>>> import suds
>>> print suds.__version__
0.4
```

Comment: Did you install python-ntlm?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - what is the install command to python-ntlm?

Comment: I don't know how you usually install your python modules, but [python-ntlm is in pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ntlm).

Answer (score 0):

As @PauloAlmeida suggested in the comment, *python-ntlm* is missing. To install using pip just type into your OS shell:

```
pip install python-ntlm
```

On Linux you might need `sudo` before the command.

You can also download the package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ntlm.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: pip install python-ntlm?

Comment: Yes, you are right @MikeSchneeberger. I fixed my answer.